# Jekyll syntax highlighting not working properly, shows rectangle around text

Tags: github, syntax, jekyll, highlight, rouge

I am attempting to change the syntax highlighting for the code in my Jekyll website.

**What I tried:**

Step 1: I put my code inside Jekyll highlighter

```
{% highlight html %} // some code here {% endHighlight %}
```

Step 2: I downloaded monokai.css file from here:
http://jwarby.github.io/jekyll-pygments-themes/languages/javascript.html and saved it into my `/assets/monokai.css`

Step 3: I imported the css via `@import url(monokai.css);` in my `main.scss`

---

**What I expect:**

[image]

**What happens:**

[image]

As you can see, it's not highlighting properly. There is a rectangle behind the code.

Why is this so? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out what's causing this by Inspecting the element and seeing what's causing the abnormal syntax highlighting.

In `base.scss`, there are a few lines that modify the `code` type.

```
pre,
code {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

All I had to do was remove the line that changes background color, and things work as expected.